# How can I switch around Views/ViewModels that are provided objects which are asychronously initialized ahead of time?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

How can I switch between Views/ViewModels when the VMs (and therefore the Views) need to take in constructor parameters whose objects are asynchronously initialized.  Or, alternatively, is there a better way to give the Views/VMs those objects?

This is my previous implementation when the View/VM didn't use constructor params.

**MainWindow.xaml**

Uses DataTemplates to switch between Views when the ContentControl changes.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:InitializerViewModel}">
        <userControls:InitializerUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:GameListingViewModel}">
        <views:GameListingView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:StreamListingViewModel}">
        <views:StreamListingView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentSection" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel, Mode=OneWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StartInitializationCommand}"/>
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
</ContentControl>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

Creates the new ViewModels and then sets CurrentViewModel to the relevant ViewModel.  When this changes, the DataTemplate switches the view based on the above DataTemplates.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private InitializerViewModel _initializerViewModel;
    public ICommand StartInitializationCommand { get; set; }    

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        StartInitializationCommand = new AwaitableDelegateCommand(InitializeAsync);
    }

    private async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        _initializerViewModel = new InitializerViewModel();
        CurrentViewModel = _initializerViewModel;
        var initializationResult = await _initializerViewModel.InitializeAsync();
        if (initializationResult)
        {
            GameListingViewModel = new GameListingViewModel(_initializerViewModel.MyObject1, _initializerViewModel.MyObject2);
            CurrentViewModel = GameListingViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

**GameListingView.xaml** (this is one of the VMs I switch in and out):

Previously defined DataContext in its xaml via:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:GameListingViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>-->
```

All of the above works as expected.

---

Now, due to new functionality, these ViewModels need to receive 1 or more objects in order to function, so I want to pass them into the constructor.  As a result, I can no longer define the DataContext in xaml, but I can use the code-behind to create them.

```
public GameListingView(ConfigSettings configSettings, GameBoxHelper gameBoxHelper)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new GameListingViewModel(configSettings, gameBoxHelper);
}
```

The problem is this requires the View's constructor to also take in the relevant objects (otherwise where would I get those objects from?), which makes the DataTemplate back in `MainWindow.xaml` no longer work.

**Xaml error message:** "Type 'GameListingView' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.  No default constructor found."

Importantly, the objects that would be passed into these ViewModels are not ready immediately; the MainWindowViewModel initializes them beforehand, which is done asychronously.  Per the above error message I think could use a `TypeConverter` (binding the to-be-passed objects to parameters and assigning them in xaml as parameters for the TypeConverter), but I don't see how that would work since they're not immediately ready (asynchronously initialized).

For reference: the intention is that when the app is loaded all the initialization is done up front (reading configuration settings from the filesystem, retrieving some data from web APIs, etc.) so that it's immediately ready when needed to make the rest of the app more responsive.  I'd prefer not move the asychronous initialization of the objects to the VMs that use them.

I do not use any MVVM frameworks.

Given all that, my question is how can I continue to switch around my Views/VMs while providing them with objects that are asychronously initialized ahead of time?

---

Comment: I think you can use DependancyProperty in the View and update the View Model whenever they change.

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how that would work?

Comment: Consider a viewmodel-centric design, where your main viewmodel has child viewmodels (or collections of child viewmodels) as properties, and the child viewmodels may have child VM properties of their own. Instead of views creating their own viewmodels, use `DataTemplate`s to implicitly assign views to viewmodels. `<ContentControl Content="{Binding BlahVM}" />` -- whatever type `BlahVM` is, if there's an implicit `DataTemplate` for it, you'll get that in the UI. `BlahVM` could be declared as object, its parent could switch in different child VMs all day long.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm already doing in the first half (the already-running code)?  The problem I have is getting past the hurdle of creating the VM and attaching it to the view when the view/vm take constructor params (and which are not immediately ready).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create the dependencies in your `App.xaml.cs` or bootstrapper class when the application starts up and then pass them along to the `MainViewModel` as constructor arguments?

Remove the `StartupUri` attribute from the `Application` root element in App.xaml and override the `OnStartup` method in App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var yourDependency = await YourClass.CreateAsync();

        MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel(yourDependency);
        MainWindow mainWindow = new WpfApplication4.MainWindow() { DataContext = vm };
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

The `MainViewModel` class will then be responsible for injecting the other view models, which it creates, with the dependencies that it is injected with by the App class.

Or if you prefer to initialize the dependencies inside the `MainViewModel` class, you could just initialize this one, i.e. the `MainViewModel`, in the `App` class.

Please refer to Stephen Cleary's blog post for more information about async factory methods and asynchronous construction: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Comment: I feel this doesn't really solve my problem.  One thing I didn't explicitly state before is that while everything is initializing I am updating the UI with statuses of each piece (using the `InitializerViewModel` & control seen in the first code snippet).  If I move the init outside of the MainVM and into App I lose that visualization, and if I separate it from MainVM into something else I still need to switch views/VMs back to the MainVM from whatever is handling the init while passing params.  It seems with this approach you'd just have a blank screen during the init.

Comment: Also, with this approach, how would I take the now-initialized params and pass them to child VM (given the `DataTemplates` I currently use to swap between Views when the `ContentControl` VM changes?  I get I can just pass it into the MainVM and now the MainVM has it, but how then does the MainVM give it to its own child VMs in a way that facilitates swapping?

Comment: The MainVM creates the child view models, right? Then you just inject them with whatever dependencies they need when you create them. The swapping is just a matter of setting the CurrentViewModel property to an instance of an initialized child view model. And if a view model is to be asynchronously initialized, of course you need to initialize it somehow. And the best way to do this is to use an async factory method.

Comment: Inject them _how_, though?  Once I add params to the constructors my `DataTemplates` start throwing errors because they need the ctor params.  How do I wire it up to pass the param through from the place init is done to the child VM?  Put another way, I know I can make a ChildVM in my MainVM and new up ChildVM(someParam) and set that to a ContentControl.  How then do I get the associated view to change along with the VM of ContentControl, given that previously I used `DataTemplates` to accomplish this which doesn't seem to work without a parameterless ctor on the view.

Comment: Post the full code for your MainViewModel and how you set the CurrentViewModel if you want me to be able to understand what you are talking about. The DataTemplates nor the views shouldn't create any view models so I don't really see the issue. Also please clarify - by code! - how you initialize your classes asynchronously.

Comment: Updated the snippets to include this.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Why can't you inject the child view models in your InitializeAsync() method in the MainViewModel?

Comment: Ahh, I finally understand what I was doing wrong.  I was mistakenly thinking I needed to associate the view to a VM (in the view's xaml/code behind).  My error was not realizing that by setting the ContentControl to a VM and using my existing DataTemplates that this was already being done.  This was exacerbated by previously change that was not working correctly, resulting in my app coming up blank when I was testing (I had erroneously thought this was because of no view being associated with the VM once I removed the `DataContext` bit from the view).  Problem solved.